# Run many OS commands in the same OS process with Python 3 to connect DB2 LUW databases

Tags: session, python-3.x, process, db2, subprocess

I'm trying to create a new process with Python 3 to run more than one command in the "same session" as only one console window was opened. It's something related to DB2 LUW databases where something is stored in memory. I created a file called "winshell.py" with this code:

```
import sys
import subprocess

def shell_execute(cmd, filename=""):
    '''
    Executes a command on SO and returns STDOUT and STDERR to a variable.
    If filename is used, then write STDOUT and STDERR to a file.

    '''

    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
        str = output.decode("1252")
        str = str.replace("\r","")    

        if filename:
            file = open(filename, "a")
            file.write(str)
            file.close()
            return "Output sent to file: "+filename
        else:
            return str

    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as cpe:
        str = cpe.output.decode("1252")
        if filename:
            file = open(filename, "a")
            file.write(str)
            file.close()
        else:
            return str

    except Exception as ex:
        format(ex)
```

Then I run from another Python program:

```
winshell.shell_execute( 'db2 "CONNECT TO AGRIA"', filename )
winshell.shell_execute( 'db2 "CONNECT RESET"', filename )
winshell.shell_execute( 'db2 "CONNECT TERMINATE"', filename )
```

The returned code is:

```
   Database Connection Information

 Database server        = DB2/NT64 10.5.0
 SQL authorization ID   = DB2ADMIN
 Local database alias   = AGRIA

SQL1024N  A database connection does not exist.  SQLSTATE=08003
DB20000I  The TERMINATE command completed successfully.
```

Clearly it runs connect statement with success, but connection is lost just when it finishes. At console prompt these 3 commands works perfectly.

Does anyone knows how to create a session in console as one single process/thread?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use ibm_db to connect to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*trying to create a new process with Python 3 to run more than one command*" -- what you are actually doing is creating three different processes. Whatever happens in one process dies with it before the next process starts.

You will need to bunch together all DB2 commands and statements in a file, then invoke the DB2 command line processor (only once) and pass the file to it as a parameter. Suppose you wrote all your commands:

```
CONNECT TO AGRIA
CONNECT RESET
CONNECT TERMINATE
```

into a file called `mydb2.txt`. You will then launch a subprocess like so:

```
winshell.shell_execute( 'db2 -f mydb2.txt', filename )
```

If you have multiline commands in your file, terminate each by a semicolon and tell the DB2 CLP that you did so:

```
winshell.shell_execute( 'db2 -tf mydb2.txt', filename )
```

Note the `-t` command line argument for "terminated".

Comment: Yup! I understood now. Basically each call to subprocess.check_output opens a new process/thread/whatever. I sent all commands to a file like "cmd.txt" terminating each one with a ` key and then used command: db2 -td` -f cmd.txt. Thx.